# How to create a XML File From Server Response (PHP)

Tags: php, xml

I have a response that I got from a server using `PHP`, it is returned in `XML` format. Unfortunately I cannot disclose the code that is in question since it is for a client, but here is a shortened version of it:

```
// server request code here…
$result = $soap>__doRequest($xmltosend,URL,$action,1); //the final part of the request process…
// $result is the returned xml that is to be converted into a separate file
```

Is there any way that I could take the returned `XML` and make a new file? If you have any questions I will be more than happy to answer them!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried ``file_put_contents( 'file.xml', $result )``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `DOMDocument`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($result);
$doc->save("/tmp/your-document.xml");
```

You can find more on this in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)